# How can I assign a list to multiple variables in R?

Tags: r

If I for example have a list of values respectively for simplicity: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), how can I assign each of those to variables A through H, where A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4 , ... H = 8, each letter matching the value at the corresponding index in the list?

I was hoping that (`LETTERS[1:8]) = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)` would work, but it does not?

Comment: There is a way via `list2env` - but you'd probably be better off just keeping it as a `list` object.

Answer (score 2):

```
   ar<-array(c(letters[1:26]), dim = c(1,26))
     for(i in 1:26) {
     assign(eval(ar[i]),i )
     }
    print(c)
```

Something like that?